# Why do I get code 400 when POST "multipart/form-datain Scrapy. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, multipartform-data

Trying hard to submit the form to no success. 
This form is supposed to redirect and return new url with PDF.
Here is how to access the page in question:

1. Start with [Search Page](http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/or_sch_1.asp)
2. Click on Document Type tab
3. Enter LP, click Search
4. Click View
5. Click Get Image
6. View PDF button is the one that Im interested in.

I need to mimic multipart formdata which looks like this:

```
            <form name="courtform" action="http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us:8080/PdfServlet/PdfServlet27" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="hostURL" value="http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/" size="60">
    <input type="hidden" name="pdfPath" value="\\wcp01zfs-03.clerk.local\files2\ORISPDF\" size="60">
    <input type="hidden" name="pdfURL" value="http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/pdf/" size="60">

    <input type="hidden" name="pages" value="1" size="60">
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="pages" value="1" size="60">-->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="22590889" size="60">
    <input type="hidden" name="mpages" value="1" size="60">
    <input type="hidden" name="doc_id" value="22590889" size="60">

            <input type="hidden" name="page1" value="image_from_file.asp?imageurl=\\ors_fs\ORImage\O\30336\O.30336.1200.0001.tif" size="60">

    <input type="hidden" name="WaterMarkText" value="1" size="60">

        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="button" type="button" value="View PDF" onclick="javascript:ValidateAndSubmit(this.form)">&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Here is part of my Scrapy code responsible for this request:

```
def get_image(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)
        url = 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us:8080/PdfServlet/PdfServlet27'
        headers = {   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                            'origin': "http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us",
                            'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
                            'dnt': "1",

                            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
                            'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
                            'cache-control': "max-age=0",
                            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                             }
        id = response.xpath("//input[@name='doc_id']/@value").extract_first()                     
        body = {'WaterMarkText': '0',
             'hostURL': 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/',
             'mpages': '1',
             'page1': 'image_from_file.asp?imageurl=\\ors_fs\\ORImage\\O\\30338\\O.30338.0268.0001.tif',
             'pages': '1',
             'pdfPath': '\\wcp01zfs-03.clerk.local\\files2\\ORISPDF\\',
             'pdfURL': 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/pdf/',
             }    

        body['doc_id'] = id
        body['id'] = id

        me = MultipartEncoder(fields=body, boundary='------WebKitFormBoundarygGHlhpHs08goICxO')
        me_body = me.to_string()

        headers['Content-Type'] =me.content_type
        headers['Content-Length'] =  me.len



        yield scrapy.Request(url, method = 'POST',  body = me_body,  callback = self.get_pdf, headers = headers)
        yield {'body':me_body}

def get_pdf(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

Whenever I run the code Im getting Response 400.
How do I mimic this form correctly?

UPDATE:

- It appears I do not need to provide Content-Length manually.
- After I removed it worked just one time. And then reverted to 404
  error.
- Is Boundary supposed to be new for every request? From what I read it
  looks like it does not, since it is just a divider with no other
  purpose.

Comment: Could you give us page url? There's probably more to it than just an input form as there are javascript calls embeded in to the form itself - there's probably more javascript involved.

Comment: @Granitosaurus Added steps to navigate to URL and Updated some recent findings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to automate the entire process of filling the form and now it seems to work just fine.

```
def get_image(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)
        item = response.meta['item']
        url = 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us:8080/PdfServlet/PdfServlet27'
        headers = {   
                            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                            'origin': "http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us",
                            'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
                            'dnt': "1",

                            'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
                            'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
                            'cache-control': "max-age=0",
                            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                        }

        body={}
        # Generate body from form
        for  i in response.xpath("//form[@name='courtform']/input"):
            name = i.xpath(".//@name").extract_first()
            val = i.xpath(".//@value").extract_first()
            body[name] =  val
        # Remove watermakr from PDF   
        body['WaterMarkText'] = '0'

        me = MultipartEncoder(fields=body, boundary='----WebKitFormBoundarygGHghpHs08goICxO')
        me_body = me.to_string()

        headers['Content-Type'] =me.content_type




        yield scrapy.Request(url, method = 'POST',  body = me_body,  callback = self.get_pdf, headers = headers, meta={'item' : item})
```